# Force Sync for Roaming Settings for Windows

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a way to force the roaming settings and files to sync?

I am using `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values` and/or `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder` to store my settings and saved games.

What I would like is a way to force a pull the roaming profile for the app when the app starts, and to push when the app loses focus.  The casual sync at some point soon is not really quick enough.  Should I giveup and write my own sync with OneDrive?

Answer (score 3):

There is no APIs available to 3rd party developers allowing them to change roaming settings. It should be fairly obvious, that it's up to the user to control their data consumption, not 3rd party applications.

Comment: Exactly what I would have said. never meddle with such things "on behalf of the user"